# Input function doesn't read the next line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn how the `input` function works but for some reason it doesn't want to read any code that's after it.

Here's my code:

```
f_name = input("enter name: ") 
print("welcome", f_name)
```

and this is the result:

```
enter name: This is my name
```

and nothing else comes after I hit enter.

Comment: The code works for me. What platform are you on, how do you run the code?

Comment: What code is after it? Because your code finishes with the `print()` which is the result.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I tried running it with Sublime text and command prompt

Comment: There isn't any code after

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For python 3.x compiler, this works fine. I guess what you can do is, print your data in one of the following ways, and see, if that works for you.

> Taking f_name as `UserName`

**1. Using f-String**

```
>>> print(f"Welcome {f_name}.")
Welcome UserName.
```

**2. String concatenation**

```
>>> print('Welcome ' + f_name)
Welcome UserName
```

**3. Using old school % formatting**

```
>>> print('Welcome %s.' % f_name)
Welcome UserName.
```

**4. Using .format()**

```
>>> print('Welcome {}.'.format(f_name))
Welcome UserName.
```

Using these you can get the output. **The code which you have pointed works out for me**, although the above solutions is what gives the output surely. Give it a go, and let us know. :)

Comment: all of the above worked although with the default python editor so It's probably a Sublime issue

Comment: Got it @user13840438. Although, it is your call to `upvote` or `mark the answer` as correct the best answer possible for the people who'd come visit your question for any help. :) Happy learning

Answer (score -2):

if it automatically closes, because nothing to execute after that so it closes try this to see the output

```
f_name = input("enter name: ") 
print("welcome", f_name)
input()
```

Answer (score -2):

For some reason running it with the default Python editor worked for me.

Sublime Text Doesn't work with `input` for some reason nor running it with cmd worked too.

Comment: Use `Visual Code` instead. It is right now preferred and it is less buggy in case of Python. :)

Comment: @user13840438 heads-up, "it is right now preferred" would need some references to back up this claim. Multiple IDEs are "right now preferred". And the only IDE I know that is actually buggy is spyder.